# How to write dictionary comprehension in this complicated case?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

An example is artificial, but I had similar problems many times.

```
db_file_names = ['f1', 'f2']  # list of database files

def make_report(filename):
    # read the database and prepare some report object
    return report_object
```

Now I want to construct a dictionary: db_version -> number_of_tables. The report object contains all the information I need.

The dictionary comprehension could look like:

```
d = {
    make_report(filename).db_version: make_report(filename).num_tables
    for filename in db_file_names
}
```

This approach sometimes works, but is very inefficient: the report is prepared twice for each database.

To avoid this inefficiency I usually use one of the following approaches:

Use temporary storage:

```
reports = [make_report(filename) for filename in db_file_names]
d = {r.db_version: r.num_tables for r in reports}
```

Or use some adaptor-generator:

```
def gen_data():
    for filename in db_file_names:
        report = make_report(filename)
        yield report.db_version, report.num_tables

d = {dat[0]: dat[1] for dat in gen_data()}
```

But it's usually only after I write some wrong comprehension, think over and realize, that clean and simple comprehension isn't possible in this case.

The question is, is there a better way to create required dictionary in such situations?

Since yesterday (when I decided to post this question) I invented one more approach, which I like more then all others:

```
d = {
    report.db_version: report.num_tables
    for filename in db_file_names
    for report in [make_report(filename), ]
}
```

but even this one looks not very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
d = {
    r.db_version: r.num_tables
    for r in map(make_report, db_file_names)
}
```

Note that in Python 3, `map` gives an iterator, thus there is no unnecessary storage cost.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a functional way:

```
from operator import attrgetter

res = dict(map(attrgetter('db_version', 'num_tables'),
               map(make_report, db_file_names)))
```

Unfortunately, functional composition is not part of the standard library, but the 3rd party [`toolz`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) does offer this feature:

```
from toolz import compose

foo = compose(attrgetter('db_version', 'num_tables'), make_report)
res = dict(map(foo, db_file_names))
```

Conceptually, you can think of these functional solutions outputting an iterable of tuples, which can then be fed directly to `dict`.